# Including Data from other columns in Aggregate Function Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
client_ref  matter_suffix    date_opened
1           1                1983-11-15 00:00:00.000
1           1                1983-11-15 00:00:00.000
1           6                2002-11-18 00:00:00.000
1           7                2005-08-01 00:00:00.000
1           9                2008-07-01 00:00:00.000
1           10               2008-08-22 00:00:00.000
2           1                1983-11-15 00:00:00.000
2           2                1992-04-21 00:00:00.000
3           1                1983-11-15 00:00:00.000
3           2                1987-02-26 00:00:00.000
4           1                1989-01-07 00:00:00.000
4           2                1987-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

I have the above table, and I simply want to return the most recent matter opened for each client, in the below format:

```
client_ref  matter_suffix    Most Recent
1          10                 2008-08-22 00:00:00.000
2          2                  1992-04-21 00:00:00.000
3          2                  1987-02-26 00:00:00.000
4          1                  1989-01-07 00:00:00.000
```

I can perform a very simple query to return the most recent (shown below), but whenever I try to include the matter_suffix data (necessary), I have problems.

Thanks in advance.

```
select client_ref,max (Date_opened)[Most Recent] from archive a
group by client_ref
order by client_ref
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL 2012 there are handy functions to make this easier but in SQL 2008 you need to do it the old way:

Find the most recent:

```
 SELECT client_ref,MAX(date_opened) last_opened
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY client_ref
```

Now join to that back:

```
SELECT client_ref,matter_suffix, date_opened
FROM YourTable YT
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT client_ref,MAX(date_opened) last_opened
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY client_ref
) MR
ON  YT.client_ref = MR.client_ref
AND YT.date_opened = MR.last_opened
```

Comment: Fantastic, this has the benefit of returning multiple values where there were more than 1 opened on the most recent date (something I didn't show in my truncated example table). Thanks all!

Comment: Glad it was useful. You might want to compare GarethD's answer for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
select client_ref,matter_suffix,max (Date_opened)[Most Recent] from archive a
group by client_ref,matter_suffix
order by client_ref
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get the latest record per client_ref:

```
SELECT  client_ref, matter_suffix, Date_opened
FROM    (   SELECT  client_ref, 
                    matter_suffix,
                    Date_opened,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_ref 
                                                    ORDER BY Date_opened DESC)
            FROM    archive a
        ) a
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

If you want to return all rows where there is more than one row with the same maximum opened date then you can use RANK:

```
SELECT  client_ref, matter_suffix, Date_opened
FROM    (   SELECT  client_ref, 
                    matter_suffix,
                    Date_opened,
                    RowNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY client_ref 
                                                    ORDER BY Date_opened DESC)
            FROM    archive a
        ) a
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select client_ref,max (matter_suffix),RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY matter_suffix ORDER BY Date_opened desc) from archive a
WHERE RN = 1
group by client_ref,Date_opened
order by client_ref,Date_opened
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining the code changes you have made with links to useful documentation, reading on the approach taken.